# Take data from a range on another sheet and return a list of column headers thus generating a type effectiveness table for Pokemon in my collection

Tags: sql, excel, google-sheets, scripting, textjoin

I apologize if for any mistakes, I am not a trained programmer, just a hobbyist.

[This is the spreadsheet I am working from.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FoHFqMdtnZYXL7cEMuqtBqS-KeLlLgLztYCmW3GzGw4/edit?usp=sharing)

It is my character sheet for a game of an old homebrew Pokémon RPG. It's a kludge, for sure.

I am working in the "Collection" tab. In the columns Strong, Weak, Immune. I would like to automatically populate these cells with a list of the appropriate types. Replicating the "Type Effectiveness" chart functionality from bulbapedia.

[An example:](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Woobat_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

[Type Effectiveness for Woobat, a Flying/Psychic Pokemon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70uNW.png)

Our dataset is located in a normally hidden tab at 'Misc Data'!A37:R55

---

So, what I need to do is take the types in columns F and G (ignoring "none") and find their corresponding rows in the dataset('Misc Data'!A37:R55) and multiply those two lines together.

Then for each cell in that row add(concatenate?) that cell's column header (currently an image, but can be edited to be text) to a list which is then displayed in the cell.

I think I need to use some combination of the functions concatenate, query, vlookup, and or clookup but I have spent a week banging my head on this and I have not been able to put together the right piece of code.

Comment: your table is not correct: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVBn4.png red cells should be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your type table is correct (which is not) use in L3:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(FILTER('Misc Data'!$B$38:$R$54, 
 REGEXMATCH('Misc Data'!$A$38:$A$54, JOIN("|", $F3, $G3)))=0.5, 
 TRANSPOSE('Misc Data'!$A$38:$A$54), )))
```

M3:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(FILTER('Misc Data'!$B$38:$R$54, 
 REGEXMATCH('Misc Data'!$A$38:$A$54, JOIN("|", $F3, $G3)))=2, 
 TRANSPOSE('Misc Data'!$A$38:$A$54), )))
```

N3:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(FILTER('Misc Data'!$B$38:$R$54, 
 REGEXMATCH('Misc Data'!$A$38:$A$54, JOIN("|", $F3, $G3)))=0, 
 TRANSPOSE('Misc Data'!$A$38:$A$54), )))
```

and drag down

[image]

---

### update for M3:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(
 (FILTER('Misc Data'!$B$38:$R$54, 
 REGEXMATCH('Misc Data'!$A$38:$A$54, JOIN("|", $F3, $G3)))=2)+ 
 (FILTER('Misc Data'!$B$38:$R$54, 
 REGEXMATCH('Misc Data'!$A$38:$A$54, JOIN("|", $F3, $G3)))=4), 
 TRANSPOSE('Misc Data'!$A$38:$A$54), )))
```

Comment: The table for this version of the game is slightly different from the video games. However, the table is easy enough to fix if something is wrong. I know steel also has an error if you compare this table to the video game. Thanks.

It looks like your code works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: Your table does not match my table. I'm not sure where you got that screen shot from.

Comment: Can we adapt the line of code for M3 to check for 2 or 4 instead of just 2?